# Undo git rebase skip on local

Tags: git, commit, rebase, git-commit, git-rebase

I did a `git rebase HEAD~3` to edit some commit messages, however when I entered the interactive mode, it showed more than my last 3 commit messages. It showed a bunch of other commits. Every time I went on each of these other commits, it warned of a `MERGE_CONFLICT` and I just did `git rebase --skip` since these weren't my commits and they were old commits as well. I kept doing `git rebase --skip` until the rebase completed. I then did `git status` and it said my branch has diverged from my last commit. I pulled from my last commit, now I have a bunch of conflicts. How do I UNDO everything BEFORE I started this REBASE. I just want to restore my branch to the last commit I pushed. After the rebase was complete, I did not force push yet so everything is still local. I want to undo all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `hard reset` with your last commit you want to go back:

```
$ git log  # copy the commit hash
$ git reset --hard <commit-hash>
```

Or, if you want local history same as remote branch then do `hard reset` local branch with remote branch:

say, local branch name is `b1`:

```
$ git fetch
$ git reset --hard origin/b1
```

Comment: I think doing that would undo all my past 3 commits to this branch? Would it be better to git reset hard with commit hash?